# Why I need refresh page for detect variable in localStorageService?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm developing a project using AngularJS with localStorageService (use for save variables),  I'm using localStorgaService in a page, for examplo /mainApp/profile, to save  a object but when I change of page for read a variable from localStorageService it don't recognize the property of object when I validate every I need to read a varable, but when I refresh the page the object is recognize . My question How to recognize the variable without refresh the page?.

I using this library: https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

**Update**
This is my factory where I save the variable

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('Profile', Profile);
    function Profile(localStorageService) {
        var service ={
            setProfile:setProfile,
            clearProfile:clearProfile,
            profileInfo:profileInfo,
            isValidated:isValidated
        };
        function isValidated()
        {
            var user = profileInfo();
            if(user===null)
                return false;
            if(user.isValidated===0)
                return false;
            return true;
        }
        function clearProfile()
        {
            return localStorageService.remove('profile');
        }
        function profileInfo()
        {
            return localStorageService.get('profile') || null;
        }
        function setProfile(profile)
        {
            localStorageService.set('profile', profile);
        }
        return service;
    }
})();
```

Comment: you face problem like after setting localstorage value you have to refresh page for display data in html right?

Comment: I'm guessing that the angular is not aware of the change in localStorage in your case, you might need a way to notify/apply the change.

Comment: More or less, I need the object for call a webservice , but depending the property of object I check that endpoint  I need.

Comment: @AnkitMishra The strange is I have a method that verifies it